# Why a run's Parent becomes null when a new Paragraph is added to the Document's Blocks?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I am trying to create a custom Undo/Redo manager for my `RichTextBox` Control. I insert a `char` in a Run and save the insertion position and the Run and other information in `Undo Stack`.

When I try to Undo, I remove the inserted `char`. After that I set the CaretPosition by this line of code:

```
CaretPosition = run.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(position);
```

Everything is fine when I do not start a new `Paragraph`.

When I press enter and start a new paragraph and I want to undo, something strange happens. Let me explain more:

**1-** I press return and a new `Paragraph` is generated.
**2-** I call `Undo`.
**3-** It reaches the above line of code and this exception is thrown: `Cannot set CaretPosition to be outside of RichTextBox.`

I think this happens because `run.Parent==null` and not its parent paragraph (This run is on the first paragraph, I mean the paragraph which I pressed return). **When I save this run into `Undo Stack`, Its parent is not null.**

I saw the source code of `ContentElement.cs` (Run's base class). It is written:

```
internal DependencyObject _parent;
internal DependencyObject Parent  { get { return _parent; } }
```

**How can this `_parent` property become null after some changes and how can I prevent this from happening?**

**Update**
(assume I write "123" in the 1st paragraph.)
The first paragraph exists in Document.Blocks and It has a run with "123" in it. But it is a different run. Does this means that a new run is generated?! I'm really confused.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is big probability that I'm wrong, but try to remove 2 last chars when it is new paragrpah. I think that you are getting this error because when you press return it inserts two characters: **\r\n**  (carret return + new line)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I handle onReturnPressed event. I insert a new Paragraph after the previous one (Document.Blocks.InsertAfter method). Does it add \r\n? (I added \r\n, but it just addes TWO paragraphs).

Comment: There is no \r\n in the paragraph's Inlines. Where they might be and How I can find them?

Comment: Some changes happen (I think /r/n addition) when I call `InsertAfter(...)` method of a `BlockCollection` to add new paragraph and I cannot track it to add it to the Undo Stack.
whether I should create a custom TextEditor or I should find a way to track those changes. I think with this explanation this answer deserves to be marked as true.